# Список рубрик в админке аккардеоном WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь найти решение:
Можно ли в админке вордпресса сделать дочерние рубрики, что б сворачивались по типу аккардеона?

Очень много дочерних рубрик и из-за этого неудобна навигация

Comment: скрин - yadi.sk/i/o8jqrbQn3H6AZS Пункт №1, №2 - это родительская категория пункты № 1.1, № 1.2, № 1.3 - это дочерние категории. необходимо сделать так, что б дочерние категории были свернуты(к примеру в аккардеон), а видны были только родительские категории

Answer (score 1):

Если вы о дочерних пунктах меню в админ-панели, то это можно сделать с помощью js примерно так:

```
(function($){
  $('.wp-submenu').css({
    'position': 'static',
    'display': 'none'
  }); //это, разумеется, можно аналогичным образом реализовать в таблице стилей, если не лень
  $('.wp-has-submenu').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.wp-submenu').slideToggle();
  })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Не пункты меню в админ панели, а конкретно список рубрик в пункте меню "Рубрики". у меня есть список список рубрик. у этих рубрик есть свои дочерние рубрики. я хочу что б в этом списке показывались только родительские рубрики, а дочерние были спрятаны в аккардеон

Comment: Никакого списка рубрик в пункте меню рубрики нет. Покажите СТРАНИЦУ, где этот список. Дайте ссылку WP или картинку внятную хотя бы.

Comment: Как я понял, в категориях постов где создаются рубрики и подрубрики, нужно реализовать аккордеон, чтобы все подрубрики сворачивались, а видимыми оставались только рубрики 1 уровня

Comment: скрин - https://yadi.sk/i/o8jqrbQn3H6AZS

Пункт №1, №2  - это родительская категория
пункты  № 1.1, № 1.2, № 1.3 - это дочерние категории.

необходимо сделать так, что б дочерние категории были свернуты(к примеру в аккардеон), а видны были только родительские категории